# What's with the random Javascript errors?

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a site in javascript and jquery.  Sometimes when I refresh I just get different random errors in firebug.  What's the deal?

edit: I'm getting errors like a variable isn't defined, when clearly it is and working, and when i refresh again, the error is gone..

using Firefox V3.5.5 Firebug V.1.5.3 and I'm primarily working with jQuery 1.4.2

Comment: Can you provide a little context, such as example code and example errors.... No one will be able to help otherwise.

Comment: What errors are you getting and where?

Comment: *much* more info needed! Like; What is the page trying to do? What js is running? What are the errors? What version of firebug / jquery / firefox are you running?

Comment: I'm not looking for a specific answer, I'm more curious as to if this is a common thing, and upon refresh again, they're gone..

Comment: Using the non-compressed version might help you track down what the error actually is.

Comment: It's likely that the errors that you are seeing are specific to the setup you have. If you could provide some script and a scenario that replicates the errors you see, we'd probably be able to provide a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. While it's more or less impossible to give a reasonable solution to such a general question, I'll just add my 2 cents' worth:

One possible source of *"undefined variable"* errors comes from including several scripts, which may or may not always load and execute in the same order. If you define a variable in one script (let's call that script `declare.js`) and use it in another (let's say `use.js`), and `use.js` is executed before `declare.js`, then you will get such an error. If the scripts execute the other way around, everything will appear fine.

If you're interested in this very topic, have a look at e.g. Steve Souders' book *[Even faster web sites](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/23/even-faster-web-sites/)*, published by O'Reilly. More specifically, look at the chapter about non-blocking script loading.

Answer (score 1):

Most common cause is that you're trying to execute Javascript *before* the DOM is loaded and thus before all HTML elements are available in the DOM tree, which in turn may cause that simple calls like `document.getElementById(id)` and jQuery's `$(selector)` may return undefined elements. That it sometimes works is pure coincidence and a matter of timing.

You need to ensure that any Javascript/jQuery code which is supposed to be executed during page load and relies on the availability of the elements in the DOM tree, also really get executed *after* the DOM is loaded. In plain vanilla JS you can do so:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById(someId);
}
```

and in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(someSelector);
});
```